# txt to csv is adding a number column

Tags: python, text-files

So I have a text file that has this in it:

```
2117,1222
1212,1223
1322,1224
etc
```

and I used this code to put it in a CSV file:

```
read_file = pd.read_csv('file.txt')
read_file.to_csv('new_file.csv)
```

but when I ran it the CSV file looked like this:

```
,2117,1222
0,1212,1223
1,1322,1224
etc
```

so I don't know what the extra 0, 1 is, but I really don't know how to stop it from being added.
Thank you!

Comment: Row numbers if I were to guess

Comment: @rdas what do you mean?

Comment: the `0`, `1`, `...` are the row numbers so just sent `index=False` if you dont want them

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
read_file.to_csv('new_file.csv', index=False)
```

it's really worth reading about additional method's parameters (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). You will still have those index values in read_file variable (try printing it), but it will disappear in the outfile.